# Python mean and standard deviation in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, dictionary

I want to calculate the mean and standard deviation of entries in a list of dictionaries. I have data of the form:

```
data = [{'x': [1,2,3,6],'y': [2.5,2,3,7],'list': "list1"},
        {'x': [2,4,5,6],'y': [3,4,5,6],'list': "list2"},
        {'x': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'y': [1.5,1,4,4,NaN,5],'list': "list3"}]
```

Now I want the mean and standard deviation of 'y' for each 'x' over the different dictionaries. I already found that I can use numpy.mean and numpy.std for the task. My problems is how to access the 'x' entries in a way that I can take the mean only for each corresponding 'y' entry of all dictionaries, because I am missing some of the entries and deal with NaNs in my data. Because I want to plot it afterwards I need to make sure that I have a full list of 'x' entries in the end too.

I want an answer like:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
mean_y = [2,2,3.5,4,5,6]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's start by reformatting your data, shall we? Because your format is weird as hell.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

data = [{'x': [1,2,3,6],'y': [2.5,2,3,7],'list': "list1"},
        {'x': [2,4,5,6],'y': [3,4,5,6],'list': "list2"},
        {'x': [1,2,3,4,5,6],'y': [1.5,1,4,4,np.NaN,5],'list': "list3"}]

b=pandas.DataFrame()    
for elem in data:
    d=dict()
    for i in range(0, len(elem['x'])):
        d[elem['x'][i]]=elem['y'][i]
    a = pandas.Series(d)
    b=b.append(a, ignore_index=True)
```

Now it's simple

```
b.mean(0)
b.std(0)
```

Comment: That looks already quite neat. I have one question, as I haven't worked with pandas before: How do I access 'x' from it? As for the weird data format: I wanted to carry some more information in the dictionary which I simplified to 'list' because it wasn't relevant for the problem and I created those in a for loop going through the files. Hence I used dictionaries. Probably the whole program looks nicer with Dataframe when I think about it, but it is probably more time consuming to change it now, then to just keep it how it is

Comment: `b.columns.values`

I recommend pandas docs, they have everything described reasonably well, and migrating to pandas hurts once but is worth it.

Comment: Thanks that works. I am looking into pandas right now. Just wondering: Is there a way to assign keys to the rows in this loop format?

Comment: Quick and dirty (ie will show you warnings, and you should think of something better) is: add this before append: `a['type']= elem['list']`

Comment: What does it do and what is it for?

Comment: It adds an extra column that you said in your previous comment you wanted.
And I can see I didn't answer your last comment. Yes, there is a way to assign keys, they are called index in pandas, and you simply add at the very end `b.set_index('type')`

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of dictionaries. To access a separate dictionary, you need to access its element in the list.

For example

```
for j in dict_list:
    avg(j['x'])
```

Should give you separate values for each list in your dictionary

Comment: I just added the result I expect. The problem is that I don't want just to average 'x' or 'y' I want to average each 'y' for each 'x' separately over the list entries and not just inside each dictionary.

Comment: Ah I see. This would be so so so much easier in Pandas :-)